# Simple debugging issue

Tags: html, css

I have two html files: index and portfolio. They use the same stylesheet. In index two divs extend to the full width of the container. However in portfolio the div only extends as long as the `<h6>`. I cannot figure out what is going on and how this could possibly be happening.

```css
.container {
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-left:18px;
    padding-right:18px;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.spacer {
    height: 2px;
}
h6 {
    position:relative;
    font-family:"code_boldregular";
    font-size:18px;
    margin: 0px;
    top: 17.5px;
    text-align:center;
}
#link1 {
    position:relative;
    height: 52.5px;
    background-color: #545454;
    width: 100%;
}
#link2 {
    height: 52.5px;
    background-color: #545454;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div id="navlinks2">
    <div id="link1" class="smalllinks"><a id="homeLNK" href="index.html"><h6>Home</h6></a>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div id="link2" class="smalllinks"><a href="portfolio.html"><h6>Portfolio</h6></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post a code for index.html and portfolio.html

Comment: Your container div is set to display:inline-block;

Comment: you are a genius kind sir! thank you for your extra set of eyes!

Comment: On a side note, fractional pixels are not very cross-browser compatible. Some browsers round .5 up, others round down, yet others try to keep the total accumulated height, rounding some heights up and some down as needed. Look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/npfftxhp/1/) with different browsers.